# mysql-cluster datausage reach the limit

Tags: mysql

My MySQLCLUSTER have reach the data usage limit as show below

```
ndb_mgm> all report memoryusage
Node 2: Data usage is 100%(2560 32K pages of total 2560)
Node 2: Index usage is 22%(531 8K pages of total 2336)
Node 3: Data usage is 100%(2560 32K pages of total 2560)
Node 3: Index usage is 22%(531 8K pages of total 2336)
```

after i search around, increase the data memory shall able to solve this error, my update as show below

```
[NDBD DEFAULT]
NoOfReplicas=2
[MYSQLD DEFAULT]
[NDB_MGMD DEFAULT]
[TCP DEFAULT]
# Managment Server
[NDB_MGMD]
HostName=the IP of THIS SERVER
# Storage Engines
[NDBD]
HostName= the IP of the FIRST SERVER
DataDir= /var/lib/mysql-cluster
DataMemory = 512M
[NDBD]
HostName=the IP of the SECOND SERVER
DataDir=/var/lib/mysql-cluster
DataMemory = 512M
# 2 MySQL Clients
# I personally leave this blank to allow rapid changes of the mysql clients;
# you can enter the hostnames of the above two servers here. I suggest you dont.
[MYSQLD]
[MYSQLD]
```

then i restart ndb_mgmd at this management node. restart data node mysql.server & ndbd. But still 100% data usage.

any step i did wrong?additional information my management node is windows xp platform & data node is solaris based.

Answer (score 1):

I googled this post and none had answered.

And I googled another post:
http://forums.mysql.com/read.php?25,517123,517665#msg-517665

According the post, we should restart the mangement node with `--initial`.

For exmaple:

```
ndb_mgmd -f D:\database\my_cluster\config.ini --initial --ndb_nodeid=1
```

This works for me. Hope help you guys.